# How to use qcut in a dataframe with conditions value from columns

Tags: python, pandas, bins

I have the following scenario in a sales dataframe, each row being a distinct sale:

```
Category  Product Purchase Value |  new_column_A   new_column_B
A         C       30             |  
B         B       50             |
C         A       100            |
```

I'm trying to find in the qcut documentation but can't find it anywhere, how to add a series of columns based on the following logic:

```
df['new_column_A'] = when category = A and product = A then df['new_column_A'] = pd.qcut(df['Purchase_Value'], q=4)

df['new_column_B' = when category = A and product = B then 
df['new_column_B'] = pd.qcut(df['Purchase_Value'], q=4)
```

Preferably i would like for this new column of percentile cut to be created in the same original dataframe.

The first thing that comes to my mind is to split the dataframe into separate ones by doing the filtering I need, but i would like to keep all these columns in the original dataframe.

Does anyone knows if this is possible and how I can do it?

Comment: What do you want to do with that after `qcut`?

Comment: I'm trying to ad a new column in my original dataframe containing the purchase value as a dimension of bins, but based on a couple of conditions as stated above. In my vision would be something like ```df['new_column] = pd.qcut(df['purchase_value'], q=4, adding additional conditions here)

Comment: So update your post with your expect outcome for your sample (compute it manually)

Comment: Done. The dataset is much larger, there would be multiple rows of occurrences therefore enough data to cut the data between percentiles.

Comment: Now with your sample of 3 rows, fill the values of your two new columns manually. I think you have to change your sample to match your logic. Else I think nobody can help you.

Comment: @Corralien the output on those columns is given by the qcut function. What i needed is not what i would get there, but if you can perform a pd.qcut with conditions. To take into account values of Purchase Value when column A and column B have a specific value.